# Most efficent AMD CPU for XMR mining?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining

I'm looking for the best AMD CPU for XMR mining which must be efficient in terms of power consumption per hash. And what is the best combination of threads, core and cache memory size to get maximum hash rate with most suitable OS. Also if I have 4 CPU do I really need 4 motherboards for each CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This verges on an opinion based question that should be closed as such. However, it's generally acknowledged that the AMD Ryzen 3000 series CPUs are probably the best overall in terms of efficiency (hash/watt) and *price* (which you overlooked). What clock settings, RAM and everything else that goes into the PC have a huge bearing on overall efficiency.

> And what is the best combination of threads, core and cache memory size to get maximum hash rate with most suitable OS

More threads and more cores gives more hashes. What OS depends on what you are most comfortable configuring.

Also, from the RandomX [readme](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX#faq) w.r.t. cache (amongst other things): "16 KiB of L1 cache, 256 KiB of L2 cache and 2 MiB of L3 cache per mining thread".

> Also if I have 4 CPU do I really need 4 motherboards for each CPU?

If you use Ryzen 3000 series CPUs you need one motherboard per CPU - they do not support multi socket motherboards.